# Asp.NET MVC3 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

It's my first project in ASP.NET MVC (MVC3) and I'm having a lot of trouble dealing with everything. All my text in the pages will be selected from database, according to language selected. For this language selection I preferred to use a Session variable. I need an **Image Link** to languages so I wrote the following lines into .cshtml page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang="Tr" }) %>'>
        <img src="../../Content/Images/flag_tr.jpg" width="40" height="20" />
    </a>
    <a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang = "En" }) %>'>
        <img src="../../Content/Images/flag_en.jpg" width="40" height="20" />
    </a>
}
```

And in the **HomeController**:

```
    public ActionResult Index()

        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        ViewBag.Selected = "Not yet selected";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String lang)
    {
        if (lang == "Tr")
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] = "Tr";
        }
        else if (lang == "En")
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] = "En";
        }
        ViewBag.Selected = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"];
        return View();
    }
```

When I click on a flag link I get "HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request." Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I should do?

P.S.: I have also tried without Form, adding a new function into Controller named **Lang** and redirect from there to Index, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be mixing Razor and WebForms syntax. When you "view source" on your page, I am sure you will not see a correct URL in your anchors:

```
<a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang="Tr" }) %>'>
```

should be:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang="Tr" })'>
```

Also, note that anchors cause an HTTPGET, even in a form, so you would need to override their behavior with JavaScript or add your `lang` checks to the HTTPGET version of your controller action. Try something like this, combining your two controller actions into one:

```
public ActionResult Index(string lang)
{
    if (lang == "Tr")
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] = "Tr";
    }
    else if (lang == "En")
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] = "En";
    }

    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    ViewBag.Selected = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Language"] ?? "Not yet selected";
    return View();
}
```

If you don't decorate this with `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`, then any HTTP verb will be mapped to this action.

Comment: Thank you so much! About the HttpGet; I placed HttpGet instead of HttpPost and I can get Tr and Eng as an output, but I'm not getting the original Index() functionality now. Sorry for my lack of knowledge I'm very new to C#, can I assume [HttpGet] here as a form of @Override in Java?

Comment: See my edit for an example controller action. I would also edit the title of your question since it has nothing to do with `Session`.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong your HomeController class name is **HomeController**.

```
<a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "HomeController", new { lang="Tr" }) %>'>
    <img src="../../Content/Images/flag_tr.jpg" width="40" height="20" />
</a>
```

So when you are specifying the Controller in Url.Action, it should only be **Home** and not ***HomeController***.

So your code in view will be like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang="Tr" }) %>'>
        <img src="../../Content/Images/flag_tr.jpg" width="40" height="20" />
    </a>
    <a href='<%: Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { lang = "En" }) %>'>
        <img src="../../Content/Images/flag_en.jpg" width="40" height="20" />
    </a>
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or you need more clarification. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I recognized/edited the question before the answer.

Comment: This isn't even valid Razor or WebForms syntax, but instead an amalgamation.